# what is the simplest way to customize google map styles to embed in webpages using iframes

Tags: css, google-maps, iframe

**How to add styles to change colors in Map attributes within iframe**

```html
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3929.7682222383455!2d78.13052821529986!3d9.95323247656748!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x3b00c5e0bd876f89%3A0x566f0a9576e2254e!2sKevell+Studio!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1463979844549" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3929.7682222383455!2d78.13052821529986!3d9.95323247656748!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x3b00c5e0bd876f89%3A0x566f0a9576e2254e!2sKevell+Studio!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1463979844549" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen>

Answer (score -1):

This is a brilliant website to style Google Maps. Use it all the time.

https://snazzymaps.com/

Comment: this might use google maps but the embed uses other site, so is not really google maps